# Is it possible to make single login framework that will work as a single unit for a .Net application and a Spring Framework Java application

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have two separate applications, one build on .net framework 4.5 and another one in spring framework. I need to redirect from .net application to java application and vice versa. So I have to built a single sign on framework.

How can I do this if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement (or use) a central authentication service.

As per the wikipedia definition:

> The Central Authentication Service (CAS) is a single sign-on protocol
>   for the web. Its purpose is to permit a user to access multiple
>   applications while providing their credentials (such as userid and
>   password) only once. It also allows web applications to authenticate
>   users without gaining access to a user's security credentials, such as
>   a password. The name CAS also refers to a software package that
>   implements this protocol.

Spring Security highlights some more information (and a sample application) for CAS [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html). Something similar should exist for .net

There are also other alternatives such as or use something like [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol), or even use [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID), but CAS was the first one to come to mind.